# Strip specific words from string

Tags: php

I want to strip whole words from a string wherever they are inside the string.

I have created an array of forbidden words:

```
$wordlist = array("or", "and", "where", ...)
```

Now I strip the words:

```
foreach($wordlist as $word)
$string = str_replace($word, "", $string);
```

The problem is that the above code also strips words that contain the forbidden words like "sand" or "more".

Comment: Pro-tip: str_replace can take an array, so you can just do `str_replace($wordlist, '', $string)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For this you can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and word boundaries:

```
$wordlist = array("or", "and", "where");

foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}

$string = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
```

**EDIT**: [Example](http://codepad.org/lrXknCO4).

Comment: Is it possible to use it with variable ? `$string = str_replace(array($row2['excl']), "", $string);` - where echo `$row2['excl'];` is a result of mysql query - I tried **"word1", "word2"** and **word1 word2** etc but without a success. Thx for any idea with syntax to try. I can post it as a new question.

Comment: Of course you can use a variable - not sure what you're trying to achieve though. It's possible it deserves another question, but can't be sure from your comment.

Comment: I placed this as a new question [PHP preg_replace where replacement array is generated from MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284601/php-preg-replace-where-replacement-array-is-generated-from-mysql-query) - may be you look at that, thx in advance

Comment: thankyou buddy. its wonderful. you save my time alot

Answer (score 8):

The str_replace also supports the input of an array. This means that you could use it in the following way:

```
str_replace(array("word1", "word2"), "", $string);
```

This means that all the words existing in the array will be replaced by an empty string. If you want specific replacements you can create an array of replacements as well.

To remove the correct words in your setup I would advise to add spaces around " or " and " where ". As you would only remove the real words and not parts of words.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The spaces idea is a simple one and would likely work in this case given the words being replaced, but in general it might present a problem at the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: But this not resolve the problem given: `also strips words that contain the forbidden words like "sand" or "more".`

Comment: OK, you right. Indeed I have done similar constructions in the very early past but taken in account the ends of the string of course. But, really I use regular expressions in these type of situations, no matter what say about the overhead.

Comment: Is it possible to use it with variable ? `$string = str_replace(array($row2['excl']), "", $string);` - where `echo $row2['excl'];` I tried _"word1", "word2"_ and _word1 word2_ but without a success. Thx for any idea with syntax to try

Comment: Note that $string(subject) as used in the example can be an array. E.g `str_replace(array("word1", "word2"), "", $array);` In that case all the words in the array will be affected. You can combine preg_replace with str_replace like this: 

`$string = "The dog, %3        \goat and 5 hens should not make the list";
 $blackList = ["dog", "goat", "hen"];
 $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $string); // $string can come from looping through an array of words.
  $finalCleanup = str_replace($blackList, "", $result);`

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
 $string = preg_replace("\b$word\b", "", $string);
```

Comment: This dosen't seems to be working.. Throwing "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it like this:

```
$filterWords = ['a','the','for'];
$searchQuery = 'a lovely day';
$queryArray = explode(' ', $searchQuery);
$filteredQuery = array_diff($queryArray, $filterWords);
```

$filteredQuery will contain ['lovely','day']

Answer (score 0):

```
$areaname = str_replace(array("to", "the","a","an","in","by","but","are","is","had","have","has"),'',$areaname);
```

i used it for this and works fine

but it will add spaces in place of these words,so you need to use replace again to chk double spaces and remove them

Answer (score 0):

If you are using utf-8 characters you will need to add /u to the regex expression

```
$string = "regadío";
$omit = ["a", "y", "o"];
$string = preg_replace('/\b(' . implode('|', $omit) . ')\b/u', '', $string);
```

Without the /u it will remove the "o" from "regadío" -> "regadí"