# Delete particular word from string

Tags: php, string

I'm extracting twitter user's profile image through JSON. For this my code is:

```
$x->profile_image_url
```

that returns the url of the profile image. The format of the url may be `"..xyz_normal.jpg"` or `"..xyz_normal.png"` or `"..xyz_normal.jpeg"` or `"..xyz_normal.gif"` etc.

Now I want to delete the "_normal" part from every url that I receive. How can I achieve this in php? I'm tired of trying it. Please help.

Comment: Show the "it" you're tired of trying.

Comment: Related: [Strip specific words from string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9342149/55075)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Php [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
str_replace('_normal', '', $var)
```

What this does is to replace '_normal' with '' (nothing) in the variable $var.
Or take a look at [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) if you need the power of regular expressions.

Comment: this might not work if the path has '_normal' somewhere else in the url?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I was making too many variables and splitting them and then using concat. Thanks!!

Comment: @Kamran that is right, so then you may need a regex and more knowledge of the data.

Answer (score 5):

The str_ireplace() function does the same job but ignoring the case

like the following

```
<?php
echo str_ireplace("World","Peter","Hello world!");
?>
```

> output : Hello Peter!

for more example you can [see](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_str_ireplace)

Answer (score 4):

The str_replace() function replaces some characters with some other characters in a string.

try something like this:

```
$x->str_replace("_normal","",$x)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$s = 'Posted On jan 3rd By Some Dude';


echo strstr($s, 'By', true);
```

This is to remove particular string from a string.

The result will be like this

```
 'Posted On jan 3rd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi replace

```
$a = array('one','two','three');
$var = "one_1 two_2 three_3";
str_replace($a, '',$var);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string erase(subscript, count)
    {
     string place="New York";
     place erase(0,2)
  }
```