# Strip specific words/phrases from string

Tags: php

I want to remove some specific words and phrases from a string and I followed the discussion at [Strip specific words from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342149/strip-specific-words-from-string).

I have created an array of forbidden words:
$wordlist = array("bayes", "full", "greater than");

My example string is:

```
$string= "my bayesian results are full of bayes and greater than anything else";
```

If I apply the following code:

```
foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}
$string = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
```

the result is:
my bayesian results are of and greater than anything else [removed word: bayes, full]

whereas I want the result to be:
my results are of and anything else [removed word: bayes, bayesian, full, greater than]

Note that I want that the forbidden word 'bayes' should remove the word 'bayesian' as well.

Comment: _“Note that I want that the forbidden word 'bayes' should remove the word 'bayesian' as well”_ – well then you shouldn’t make your regular expression require a word boundary after the search word maybe, hm?

Comment: This is a clbuttic problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.*?` before the ending boundary. It would match non-greedily till the boundary is reached.
Like this -

```
$word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '.*?\b/';
                                          ^^^
```

It outputs -

```
my  results are  of  and  anything else
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$string = "my bayesian results are full of bayes and greater than anything else";
$forbidden = array('/bayes(\w+)/','/full(\w+)/');
$result = preg_replace($forbidden , array(), $string);
print_r($result);
```

This code takes the string, tries to match an array of regex patterns ($forbidden) to the string and replaces them with an empty value.

It looks for words starting with bayes or full and stops looking when it finds whitespace.

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Comment: `/bayes(\w+)/` wont catch "bayes" only "bayesian". Modify to be `/baye(\w+)/`

Answer (score 0):

First split the string into words then check each word against each banned word and remove it if necessary.

```
$string = "my bayesian results are full of bayes and greater than anything else";
$banned_words = array("bayes", "full", "greater than");
$words = explode(' ',$string);

foreach($words as $key => $word) {
    foreach($banned_words as $banned_word) {
        if(false !== stripos($word,$banned_word)) {
            unset($words[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

$string = implode(' ',$words);
```

Finally remove any 1+ word full matches

```
print str_ireplace($banned_words,'',$string);
```